# UK Visa validity from arrival or depature?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for UK visitor visa and was granted one with a start date of April 15. I will be leaving US April 14, and arriving London April 15, will this visa be valid? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

UK visas are valid for entry from the start date. The expiry date is the latest date by which you must leave. Your departure date doesn’t matter - you can enter on any day between the two beginning with the start date.
One conceivable problem with departing the day before would be if your flight was scheduled to land in the UK shortly after 00:01 the following day, but arrived ahead of schedule prior to midnight on the departure date.

Comment: My concern is that my visa only valid on my arrival in London (Apr 15) but my departure from Chicago is Apr 14. Will there be any complication?

Comment: @user93072 The visa must be valid on arrival, it doesn't matter when you depart.

Comment: +1 I think there needs to be a canonical on this question to refer to and close subsequent questions by reference. It comes up way too much.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it is a relief that I should not worry not being able to board

Comment: @user93072 it may help to call the airline first, just to be sure.